# Circle in SwiftUI doesn't show in my iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I have two `Circle`s to show a circle progress bar, one of these is the progress the another one is the background, but the progress circle doesn't show in my iPhone. This is my code:

```
struct ProgressBarView: View {

@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
    
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Group {
                
                Circle()
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 14.0)
                    .opacity(colorScheme == .dark ? 1 : 0.3)
                
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0.0, to: 0.3 )
                    .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 14.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .blue : Color("DarkBlue"))
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 270.0))
                
                Text("16hrs")
                    .font(.system(size: 22))
                    .fontWeight(.regular)
            }//: Group
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : Color("DarkBlue"))

        }
}}
```

[image: assets]

Comment: Because you don't have a color named exactly "DarkBlue". I had the same symptoms when I pasted the code until I changed `Color("DarkBlue")` to a standard color.

Comment: I have "DarkBlue" in my assets colors

Comment: Test it yourself. Change the Color("DarkBlue") to `.red` or `.green`, etc. It works fine.

Comment: I've been change it like that, and it didn't work

Comment: Well, your code is working for everyone else. Therefore, the error is in another part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The same error happens... because you're trying to call a color that doesn't exist (I'm guessing). Do note that the `Color` declaration requires that you both spell and capitalize correctly. You must either add this color to the Asset Catalog or, as @Yrb stated above,

> I  had the same symptoms when I pasted the code until I changed Color("DarkBlue") to a standard color.

If you do want a good Dark Blue color, I would suggest hex `#00008b`.

Comment: The DarkColor exist in my assets

Comment: Try taking it out of the `Colors` folder. Also, take a look and see if it works without the whole `ColorScheme` thing - try just using it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to add a Color Set to your Assets as it's missing. You can make a custom color using their color panel and set it to whatever you think DarkBlue should be.

**Update:** I don't see anything wrong with your code, and your Color set in your assets looks fine. Try another Color set and start fresh?

[image: colorset]

[image: example]

Comment: I have the color in the assets and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you update your answer with a screenshot of what you have in your assets?

Comment: updated! Look the changes